# Index numpy array with two arrays given start and end for each column

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a 2D numpy array A with dimensions NxM
I have two arrays start and end with dimensions Nx1

For each row k given by A[k,:] I want to set the columns from start[k] to end[k] to 0:

```
A[:,start:end]=0
```

However, I get the error

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

If I just index

```
A[:,start]=0
```

it works. But this is not what I want to achieve.

The length of start[k]:end[k] differs for each k

Comment: The start and end values are results of calculations with numpy arrays. Also, the number of elements given by start[k]:end[k] differs for each k

Comment: start[k]:end[k] differs for each k. I don't want to extract an array, I just want to replace the values in that range

Comment: What's the length of start, end indices array? If that's not too large, simply loop though @torpedo.

Comment: The length is 100000 and it is repeated on 100 different matrices. I was hoping to get it done faster than with a loop

Comment: @jpp, length is and can not be constant. I am aware that I can not create jagged arrays. However I am only zeroing the values in an array.

Comment: Are you using the same start, end indices arrays across all 100 matrices?

Comment: @Divakar, unfortunately not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the length of the start and end indexing arrays - `starts` and `ends` of larg-ish lengths, we could create a mask of those places -

```
r = np.arange(A.shape[1])
mask = (r >= np.asarray(starts)[:,None]) & (r < np.asarray(ends)[:,None])
A[mask] = 0
```

Sample run -

```
In [47]: np.random.seed(0)

In [48]: A = np.random.randint(10,100,(4,10))

In [49]: A
Out[49]: 
array([[54, 57, 74, 77, 77, 19, 93, 31, 46, 97],
       [80, 98, 98, 22, 68, 75, 49, 97, 56, 98],
       [91, 47, 35, 87, 82, 19, 30, 90, 79, 89],
       [57, 74, 92, 98, 59, 39, 29, 29, 24, 49]])

In [50]: starts = np.array([2,4,1,0,])

In [51]: ends = np.array([4,7,5,2])

In [52]: r = np.arange(A.shape[1])
    ...: mask = (r >= np.asarray(starts)[:,None]) & (r < np.asarray(ends)[:,None])
    ...: A[mask] = 0

In [53]: A
Out[53]: 
array([[54, 57,  0,  0, 77, 19, 93, 31, 46, 97],
       [80, 98, 98, 22,  0,  0,  0, 97, 56, 98],
       [91,  0,  0,  0,  0, 19, 30, 90, 79, 89],
       [ 0,  0, 92, 98, 59, 39, 29, 29, 24, 49]])
```

With a small-ish starts, ends arrays or if `A` is a very large array, simply looping might be better.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know what you are talking about. It perfectly works for me:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
>>> a[:, 1:2] = 0
>>> a
array([[1, 0, 3],
       [4, 0, 6],
       [7, 0, 9]])
```

To debug your program, try to print out types of start and end before you have

```
A[:,start:end]=0
```

It may help you find out the problem.

Comment: start and end are arrays, so each row has a different start and end.